# change datepicker style iphone

Tags: iphone, datepicker

the date Picker I have right now has the style like : mm/dd/YYYY and it displays at Textfield in "YYYY/MM/DD".

how can I change my code so that the datepicker shown is also changed to " YYYY/MM/DD".
Here is my code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init] ;
        [comps setYear:-10];
        NSDate *maximumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
        [comps setYear:-10];
        NSDate *minimumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];



        UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [datePicker setMaximumDate:maximumDate];
        [datePicker setMinimumDate:minimumDate];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.Birthday setInputView:datePicker] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `locale` property of the DatePicker. The documentation says:

The default value is the current locale as returned by the currentLocale property of NSLocale, or the locale used by the date picker’s calendar. Locales encapsulate information about facets of a language or culture, such as the way dates are formatted.

It is generally considered poor form to force a user to select in a fashion not typical to their locale.

Comment: here is my locale information:  
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];    
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
        [dictionary setObject:df forKey:kAPIDateFormatter];    even when I am chaning this tha format remains the same!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't modify the UIDatePicker default style.

You can change to many formats after the date is picked by using **[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

**Example:**

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
```